# jquery restart a toggle function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a custom clickToggle function

it does

tab 1st toggle - open div
tab 2nd toggle - close div

after 1st toggle, the user can also close the div by clicking outside the div, without activating toggle2. the next time i want to open the div, it will continued at 2nd toggle, which is a bad bug.

So basically i'm asking if there is anyway i can end/restart the toggle function midway, so that if the user click outside of the div, the next time i click on the tab it will start at 1st toggle again, instead of continuing at 2nd toggle.

Is there something like a reset that i can do to restart the toggle function? Quite desperate about this been figuring for a day.

```
$(function () {
    $("#toggle").clickToggle(function () { // toggle 1 open
        $(".log").html("click Toggle1, show tab panel, isToggle = true");
        $("#toggle_content").animate({width:'toggle'},350);
        $(".container").addClass("overlay-disable");

        // alternative exit(i want the toggle function to restart 
        // if this function runs, if not the next time i want to open the tab through
        // toggle 1, it will continue at toggle 2 instead which is a bad bug as that 
        //was suppose to be a exit.
        $(".container").click(function() { 
            $(".container").unbind("click").removeClass("overlay-disable");
            $(".log").html("panel hide success, isToggle = false");
            $("#toggle_content").hide();

        });
    },function() { // toggle 2 exit
        $(".container").unbind("click").removeClass("overlay-disable");
        $(".log").html("click Toggle2, hide tab panel");
        $("#toggle_content").animate({width:'toggle'},350);

    });
});
```

clickToggle is a custom plugin to toggle between 2 functions in each time i click the tab, it worked smoothly for just opening and exiting, but once i added a alternative exit i can't get a solution to restart the toggle function back to toggle1 if alternative exit is activated.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eekxzq1u/

when u click on tab, it pop a grey box, when u click on tab again, it close smoothly.
But when you tab out, the tab won't be working smoothly anymore

Comment: We are also quite desperate to see your code. Because imagining is quite hard for us.

Comment: @shoaib chikate done, sorry

Comment: You're asking us to debug the custom function `clickToggle` which you didn't give to us.

Comment: Please provide a REAL [**fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/) with your problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid using plugin by implementing a simple state-machine approach. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eekxzq1u/1/). You will need

1. Array of functions to be invoked on click `states`
2. Variable to store current state `currentState`
3. And a handler to invoke state functions on click `run`

Code:

```
   var states = [function () { // click button 1st toggle
        $(".log").html("click Toggle1, show tab panel, isToggle = true");
        $("#toggle_content").animate({width:'toggle'},350);
        $(".container").addClass("overlay-disable");
        currentState = 1; //change state

        $(".container").click(function() {
            $(".container").unbind("click").removeClass("overlay-disable");
            $(".log").html("panel hide success, isToggle = false");
            $("#toggle_content").hide();
            currentState = 0; //change state
        });
    },
      function() {
        $(".container").unbind("click").removeClass("overlay-disable");
        $(".log").html("click Toggle2, hide tab panel");
        $("#toggle_content").animate({width:'toggle'},350);
          currentState = 0; //change state

    }], 
    currentState = 0,
    run = function() {
       return states[currentState].apply(this, arguments);        
    };

$("#toggle").click(run);
```

Comment: thanks, exactly what i need. But can you explain to me as it would be good for me what it does, i don't understand run = function() {
       return states[currentState].apply(this, arguments);        
    };

Comment: It is just a function that invokes another function. Which part of the code is not clear?

Comment: just this line return states[currentState].apply(this, arguments);   , you see i don't really know how return works. I will go search about it online. Thanks @yury tarabanko